# Nginx - как разрешить запуск только одного скрипта?

Tags: nginx

По техническим причинам необходимо разрешить выполнение только одного php скрипта, а конкретно - index.php в корневой директории сайта. Все остальные скрипты с другими именами должны игнорироваться и перенаправляться на основной без параметров. Как это сделать красиво?

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант, в начале location, принимающего обращения к скриптам, поставить правило:

```
rewrite ^/(.php)$ /index.php last;
```

*Не уверен будет ли работать для скриптов из вложенных каталогов.*